# jquery ui draggable/droppable, swap draggables on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

currently I have 3 draggable items setup with 3 ID's and the class .word.

I've successfully got them to drop into place and also revert back to their initial position when dragged out of the dropzone.

my main goal is to have the draggables swap when dropped into dropzone.

so eg: #word1 is in dropzone, when #word2 is dragged to dropzone, #word1 should return to initial position and #word2 should snap to dropzone and so on.

I've tried various things but can't work out the logic properly. thanks community.

EDIT:

@bipen sorry for that, code is as follows so far:

```
HTML
<div id="line"></div>
<img src="resources/word1_correct.png" id="word1" class="word" />
<img src="resources/word2.png" id="word2" class="word" />
<img src="resources/word3.png" id="word3" class="word" />


JS
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

var p = $("#word1");
var offset = p.offset();

var p2 = $("#word2");
var offset2 = p2.offset();

var p3 = $("#word3");
var offset3 = p3.offset();

$(".word").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 0,
    start: function(event, ui) {
    // Log start dragged position to element data
}


// end .word draggable
});

$("#line").droppable({
    accept: '.word',
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).css('top',$(this).position().top);
    $(ui.draggable).css('left',$(this).position().left);
    $(ui.draggable).attr('class', 'dropped');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.word');
    $('#word1').draggable('destroy');
    $('#word1').offset({ top: offset.top, left: offset.left});
    $('#word1').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 0,
    });

    $('#word2').draggable('destroy');
    $('#word2').offset({ top: offset2.top, left: offset2.left})
    $('#word2').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 0,
    });

    $('#word3').draggable('destroy');
    $('#word3').offset({ top: offset3.top, left: offset3.left})
    $('#word3').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 0,
    });


    }

// end #line droppable  
});




//end document ready
});
```

Comment: post your code.... so that we don't have to write eveything from start...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "#dropzone" ).droppable({
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).html(); //empty the dropzone 
           ui.appendTo( this ); //add the dragged word to it
   }
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. I'm going to work on it trying an IF statement and see if I can come up with something. Thanks Bipen.

Answer (score 0):

you just move position draggable :

example is i have two droppable (droppable1,droppable2) and two draggable (draggable,draggable2)

in document.ready i move position draggable1 & draggable2 to droppable1, check this code :

```
var d1left = $("#droppable1").position().left + 20;
var d1top = $("#droppable1").position().top + 25;
$("#draggable1").css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': (d1left*1) + 'px', 'top': ((d1top*1)+15) + 'px'});
$("#draggable2").css({'position': 'absolute', 'left': (d1left*1) + 'px', 'top': ((d1top*2)+20) + 'px'});
```

perhaps this can help you, tq